# ImageButton Rounded Corners doesn't work

Tags: android, xml

In the XML-preview I have the rounded corners of the ImageButtons, but if I start the emulator or my device I haven't the rounded corners.
What's the reason? Hope for some help.

roundedcorner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
        android:src="@drawable/one"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonTwo"
        android:src="@drawable/two"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Emulator:
[image: Emulator:]
 
Preview:
[image: Preview:]

Comment: Can you share a ScreenShot about your output?

Comment: What is the API version of the emulator? Please share your src drawables as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change roundedcorner.xml to;

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="?colorAccent" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

and the set as background to the `ImageButton`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
        android:src="@drawable/one"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonTwo"
        android:src="@drawable/two"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice the misspelt `@drawable/roundcorner` when you mean `@drawable/roundedcorner`?

Comment: I mean rounded cornder sorry. Main MainActivity only extends Activity. I don't use AppCompat

Comment: Without `AppCompat`, `android:color="?android:colorAccent"` only work as from `API 21`.

Comment: Have you declared `android:colorAccent` in your `styles.xml`?

Comment: Try replacing the `"?android:colorAccent"` with a direct color code, say `color="#00ffff"` and see what happens.

Comment: That exact code, copy/pasted works on my side. So check for errors, maybe elsewhere... A screenshot would be nice.

Comment: a screenshot of the app?

Comment: I noticed that it doesn't work with the imageview. If I try it on a edittext it works fine.